# How do you control which match is chosen when running a `SELECT INNER JOIN WHERE t1.column=t2.column` and there are multiple matches?

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have two MySQL tables:

**Products**

```
title    id    hidden   categories
Thing    10    N        12,14,
Stuff    23    N        12,
Object   41    Y        13,14
```

**Images**

```
filename     id    productid
aca8t.jpg    1     10
ev7ha.jpg    2     10
mscpk.jpg    3     10
asges.jpg    4     23
fcuhg.jpg    5     23
scvfe.jpg    6     41
vf6kl.jpg    7     41
fgszy.jpg    8     41
```

I build a list of product titles and images using a SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT     t1.title,
           t1.id,
           t1.hidden,
           t1.categories,
           t2.image
FROM       products AS t1
INNER JOIN pimage   AS t2
WHERE      t1.categories LIKE '%$categoryId%'
AND        t1.id=t2.productid
AND        NOT t1.hidden='Y'
GROUP BY   id
ORDER BY   id ASC
```

After running this query, I have a list of non-hidden products in a given category, as well as their IDs and one image.  However, the selection of an image appears to be random.  Sometimes it's alphabetical, sometimes it's the lowest ID, and sometimes it's neither.  However, it's always the same when the filenames for a given productid stay the same.

This is in use on a small website where product managers upload photos of a product and its accessories.  The first photo should be used as a thumbnail and visible on the category page.  However, a photo of a random accessory is sometimes selected as the thumbnail image, and the product managers have to re-upload the images until the right one gets selected.  This process is onerous.

How can I modify the SQL statement so that the first photo (the filename with the lowest `images.id`) is selected?

Comment: You are using `GROUP BY` inappropriately, because you have columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  Hence, as MySQL *clearly* documents, you get a value from an indeterminate matching row (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html).

Comment: your INNER JOIN statement is incomplete for what you need even thought it is syntactically valid. You should use ON clouse to join columns as described here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx . If you are usign WHERE you actually don't need INNER JOIN at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a correlated subquery instead of a `join`/`group by`:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (SELECT i.image
        FROM pimage i
        WHERE p.id = i.productid 
        ORDER BY i.image ASC
        LIMIT 1
       ) as image
FROM  products p
WHERE p.categories LIKE '%$categoryId%' AND
      p.hidden <> 'Y'
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

Comment: To get the pimage with the lowest `id` value for each product, use **`ORDER BY i.id ASC`** in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

If this statement were executed on another relational database (other than MySQL/MariaDB), it would throw an error with a message along the lines of "non-aggregates in SELECT list not included in GROUP BY".

But A MySQL specific extension to GROUP BY allows this query to execute in MySQL, but as you've noticed, the values returned for the non-aggregates in the SELECT list are *indeterminate*, MySQL will return a value from *some* row.

The normal pattern is to use a `MAX()` or `MIN()` aggregate function to "control" which value is returned.

In your case, that would work to return the minimum `id` value, but getting the other values on that same row is more problematic. If you only need to return a few columns, you can use a correlated subqueries in the SELECT list.

Another approach is to use an inline view and a join operation.

```
  SELECT t1.title
       , t1.id
       , t1.hidden
       , t1.categories
       , t2.image
    FROM products t1
    JOIN ( SELECT n.productid
                , MIN(n.id) AS min_id
             FROM pimage n
            GROUP BY n.productid
         ) m
      ON m.productid = t1.id
    JOIN pimage t2
      ON t2.id = m.min_id
   WHERE t1.categories LIKE '%$categoryId%'
     AND t1.hidden='Y'
   GROUP BY t1.id
   ORDER BY t1.id ASC
```

This approach is useful when you need to return a additional columns from the row with the "minimum" id. For example, you also needed to include in the SELECT list:

```
       , t2.fee
       , t2.fi
       , t2.fo
       , t2.fum
```